# Sorting Keys in a Dictionary with multiple decimal points and String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am using Python 3.5. I have a dictionary with entries:

```
myresult = { '6.1.2 & 6.3.2, abcd' : xyz, 
             '6.10.2 & 6.12.2, hjsd' : xyz, abc, ssd
             '6.2.2 & 6.4.2, abcd' : asd,
             '6.9.2 & 6.11.2, qwer' : tzu, 
             '6.21.2 & 6.23.2, xzty' : asd }
```

Expected output is

```
>>>'6.1.2 & 6.3.2, abcd' : xyz
   '6.2.2 & 6.4.2, abcd' : asd
   '6.9.2 & 6.11.2, qwer' : tzu,
   '6.10.2 & 6.12.2, hjsd' : xyz, abc, ssd
   '6.21.2 & 6.23.2, xzty' : asds
```

i.e., I need the numbers to be sorted after the decimal point as normal integers.

I tried using `for key in sorted(myresult.keys()): print(key)`

The output was

```
'6.1.2 & 6.3.2, abcd' : xyz
'6.10.2 & 6.12.2, hjsd' : xyz, abc, ssd
'6.2.2 & 6.4.2, abcd' : asd
'6.21.2 & 6.23.2, xzty' : asds
'6.9.2 & 6.11.2, qwer' : tzu
```

Any Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that is to supply a key function to `sorted`:

```
def num_keyfn(something):
    parts = something.split(".")
    return tuple(int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in parts)

for key in sorted(myresult.keys(), key=num_keyfn):
    print(key)
```

This prints:

```
6.1.2 & 6.3.2, abcd
6.2.2 & 6.4.2, abcd
6.9.2 & 6.11.2, qwer
6.10.2 & 6.12.2, hjsd
6.21.2 & 6.23.2, xzty
```

This is not perfect yet, as it won't work if the difference is in the middle somewhere, but you can see the principle and adapt it to your needs.

---

When `sorted` (or `.sort`) is given a `key` function, instead of comparing elements directly, it will first call this function on the element. For example, to sort strings by length, you can supply the argument `key=len`.

Python can compare tuples: `(2,4)` is smaller than `(2,5)`.

In my answer, I split the strings on every dot into parts, and cast to `int` any part that `.isnumeric()`. While `"10"` is smaller than `"2"`, `10` is not smaller than `2`.

Comment: Sorry mate, it produces the same output which as `sorted(myresult.keys())`

Comment: @Seetharama I changed it a few seconds ago, did you try it with the latest version?

Comment: Works like a charm!! Could you care to explain a bit? :-)

Comment: Added some explanation below the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!! Newbie here :)

Comment: @L3viathon A short question, Can it somehow be extended to sorting the strings where if there are keys like `[6.1.2 & 6.3.2, XYZ], [6.1.2 & 6.3.2 ABC]` be sorted as `[6.1.2 & 6.3.2, ABC], [6.1.2 & 6.3.2, XYZ]` ?

Comment: @Seetharama That should already be the case. When a part can't be cast to an int, it stays a string.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not sorting the strings after the integers

Comment: @Seetharama I see, I made a mistake. The corrected `num_keyfn` is in the answer now.

Comment: Now it's perfect!